# Open file dialog with slide down

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4, osx-lion

I have done quite some cocoa-touch stuff, but am still new to cocoa. I would like to present a "select file" view where the users is only alowed to choose files of a certain filetype (e.g. txt). 
However, I want the view to slide down...

By sliding down, I mean something like this:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3077127/objc-openFIle.mov

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a 'sheet'. To achieve this you use the method `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` of your NSOpenPanel.